# Code getting slow when using transform:rotate();

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Today I making a css project on codepen in which i want make a hoverable area which change its property on hover. for that i use many "p" tag and make some control. But when i use **transform:rotate();**  property on p tags the  hover
is getting vey slow. 
When i am not using transform on tags it works smoothly .So is there any way to improve the speed when using transform property. 
Also is there any ways so not need copy paste many

tags.

**Note:** *the transform property works but very slow. i checked in many browser but it slow on all*

this is the code link

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("p").addClass('def_bg def_hov_bg def_time def_anim');

  $("#bg_col_1").click(function() {
    $(".def_bg").toggleClass("bg_1");
    $(".def_bg").removeClass("bg_2 bg_3 bg_9 bg_4 bg_5 bg_6 bg_7 bg_8");
  });
  $("#bg_col_2").click(function() {
    $(".def_bg").toggleClass("bg_2");
    $(".def_bg").removeClass("bg_1 bg_3 bg_4 bg_9 bg_5 bg_6 bg_7 bg_8");
  });
  $("#bg_col_3").click(function() {
    $(".def_bg").toggleClass("bg_3");
    $(".def_bg").removeClass("bg_1 bg_2 bg_4 bg_9 bg_5 bg_6 bg_7 bg_8");
  });
  $("#bg_col_4").click(function() {
    $(".def_bg").toggleClass("bg_4");
    $(".def_bg").removeClass("bg_1 bg_2 bg_3 bg_9 bg_5 bg_6 bg_7 bg_8");
  });
  $("#bg_col_5").click(function() {
    $(".def_bg").toggleClass("bg_5");
    $(".def_bg").removeClass("bg_1 bg_2 bg_3 bg_4 bg_9 bg_6 bg_7 bg_8");
  });
  $("#bg_col_6").click(function() {
    $(".def_bg").toggleClass("bg_6");
    $(".def_bg").removeClass("bg_1 bg_2 bg_3 bg_4 bg_5 bg_9 bg_7 bg_8");
  });
  $("#bg_col_7").click(function() {
    $(".def_bg").toggleClass("bg_7");
    $(".def_bg").removeClass("bg_1 bg_2 bg_3 bg_4 bg_5 bg_6 bg_9 bg_8");
  });
  $("#bg_col_8").click(function() {
    $(".def_bg").toggleClass("bg_8");
    $(".def_bg").removeClass("bg_1 bg_2 bg_3 bg_4 bg_5 bg_6 bg_7 bg_9");
  });
  $("#bg_col_9").click(function() {
    $(".def_bg").toggleClass("bg_9");
    $(".def_bg").removeClass("bg_1 bg_2 bg_3 bg_4 bg_5 bg_6 bg_7 bg_8");
  });



  $("#hov_col_1").click(function() {
    $(".def_hov_bg").toggleClass("hov_1");
    $(".def_hov_bg").removeClass("hov_2 hov_3 hov_4 hov_5 hov_6 hov_7 hov_8 hov_9");
  });
  $("#hov_col_2").click(function() {
    $(".def_hov_bg").toggleClass("hov_2");
    $(".def_hov_bg").removeClass("hov_1 hov_3 hov_4 hov_5 hov_6 hov_7 hov_8 hov_9");
  });
  $("#hov_col_3").click(function() {
    $(".def_hov_bg").toggleClass("hov_3");
    $(".def_hov_bg").removeClass("hov_2 hov_1 hov_4 hov_5 hov_6 hov_7 hov_8 hov_9");
  });
  $("#hov_col_4").click(function() {
    $(".def_hov_bg").toggleClass("hov_4");
    $(".def_hov_bg").removeClass("hov_2 hov_3 hov_1 hov_5 hov_6 hov_7 hov_8 hov_9");
  });
  $("#hov_col_5").click(function() {
    $(".def_hov_bg").toggleClass("hov_5");
    $(".def_hov_bg").removeClass("hov_2 hov_3 hov_4 hov_1 hov_6 hov_7 hov_8 hov_9");
  });
  $("#hov_col_6").click(function() {
    $(".def_hov_bg").toggleClass("hov_6");
    $(".def_hov_bg").removeClass("hov_2 hov_3 hov_4 hov_5 hov_1 hov_7 hov_8 hov_9");
  });
  $("#hov_col_7").click(function() {
    $(".def_hov_bg").toggleClass("hov_7");
    $(".def_hov_bg").removeClass("hov_2 hov_3 hov_4 hov_5 hov_6 hov_1 hov_8 hov_9");
  });
  $("#hov_col_8").click(function() {
    $(".def_hov_bg").toggleClass("hov_8");
    $(".def_hov_bg").removeClass("hov_2 hov_3 hov_4 hov_5 hov_6 hov_7 hov_1 hov_9");
  });
  $("#hov_col_9").click(function() {
    $(".def_hov_bg").toggleClass("hov_9");
    $(".def_hov_bg").removeClass("hov_2 hov_3 hov_4 hov_5 hov_6 hov_7 hov_8 hov_1");
  });



  $("#t-1").click(function() {
    $(".def_time").toggleClass("td-1");
    $(".def_time").removeClass("td-2 td-3 td-4 td-5 td-6 td-7 td-8 td-9 td-10 td-11");
  });
  $("#t-2").click(function() {
    $(".def_time").toggleClass("td-2");
    $(".def_time").removeClass("td-1 td-3 td-4 td-5 td-6 td-7 td-8 td-9 td-10 td-11");
  });
  $("#t-3").click(function() {
    $(".def_time").toggleClass("td-3");
    $(".def_time").removeClass("td-2 td-1 td-4 td-5 td-6 td-7 td-8 td-9 td-10 td-11");
  });
  $("#t-4").click(function() {
    $(".def_time").toggleClass("td-4");
    $(".def_time").removeClass("td-2 td-3 td-1 td-5 td-6 td-7 td-8 td-9 td-10 td-11");
  });
  $("#t-5").click(function() {
    $(".def_time").toggleClass("td-5");
    $(".def_time").removeClass("td-2 td-3 td-4 td-1 td-6 td-7 td-8 td-9 td-10 td-11");
  });
  $("#t-6").click(function() {
    $(".def_time").toggleClass("td-6");
    $(".def_time").removeClass("td-2 td-3 td-4 td-5 td-1 td-7 td-8 td-9 td-10 td-11");
  });
  $("#t-7").click(function() {
    $(".def_time").toggleClass("td-7");
    $(".def_time").removeClass("td-2 td-3 td-4 td-5 td-6 td-1 td-8 td-9 td-10 td-11");
  });
  $("#t-8").click(function() {
    $(".def_time").toggleClass("td-8");
    $(".def_time").removeClass("td-2 td-3 td-4 td-5 td-6 td-7 td-1 td-9 td-10 td-11");
  });
  $("#t-9").click(function() {
    $(".def_time").toggleClass("td-9");
    $(".def_time").removeClass("td-2 td-3 td-4 td-5 td-6 td-7 td-8 td-1 td-10 td-11");
  });
  $("#t-10").click(function() {
    $(".def_time").toggleClass("td-10");
    $(".def_time").removeClass("td-2 td-3 td-4 td-5 td-6 td-7 td-8 td-9 td-1 td-11");
  });
  $("#t-11").click(function() {
    $(".def_time").toggleClass("td-11");
    $(".def_time").removeClass("td-2 td-3 td-4 td-5 td-6 td-7 td-8 td-9 td-10 td-1");
  });




  $("#e-1").click(function() {
    $(".def_anim").toggleClass("ef-1");
    $(".def_anim").removeClass("ef-2 ef-3 ef-4 ef-5 ef-6 ef-7 ef-8");
  });
  $("#e-2").click(function() {
    $(".def_anim").toggleClass("ef-2");
    $(".def_anim").removeClass("ef-1 ef-3 ef-4 ef-5 ef-6 ef-7 ef-8");
  });
  $("#e-3").click(function() {
    $(".def_anim").toggleClass("ef-3");
    $(".def_anim").removeClass("ef-2 ef-1 ef-4 ef-5 ef-6 ef-7 ef-8");
  });
  $("#e-4").click(function() {
    $(".def_anim").toggleClass("ef-4");
    $(".def_anim").removeClass("ef-2 ef-3 ef-1 ef-5 ef-6 ef-7 ef-8");
  });
  $("#e-5").click(function() {
    $(".def_anim").toggleClass("ef-5");
    $(".def_anim").removeClass("ef-2 ef-3 ef-4 ef-1 ef-6 ef-7 ef-8");
  });
  $("#e-6").click(function() {
    $(".def_anim").toggleClass("ef-6");
    $(".def_anim").removeClass("ef-2 ef-3 ef-4 ef-5 ef-1 ef-7 ef-8");
  });
  $("#e-7").click(function() {
    $(".def_anim").toggleClass("ef-7");
    $(".def_anim").removeClass("ef-2 ef-3 ef-4 ef-5 ef-6 ef-1 ef-8");
  });
  $("#e-8").click(function() {
    $(".def_anim").toggleClass("ef-8");
    $(".def_anim").removeClass("ef-2 ef-3 ef-4 ef-5 ef-6 ef-7 ef-1");
  });




});
```

```css
p {
  margin: -5px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 9px;
}

.def_bg {
  background: #000;
}


/*default background-color*/

.def_hov_bg:hover {
  background: #fff;
}


/*default hover color     */

.def_time {
  transition: all .5s;
}


/*default transition time */

.def_time:hover {
  transition: all 0s;
}

.def_anim {
  transform: none;
}


/*for background change*/

.bg_1 {
  background: #4559EF;
}

.bg_2 {
  background: #EF2626;
}

.bg_3 {
  background: #14A91B;
}

.bg_4 {
  background: #835C3B;
}

.bg_5 {
  background: #DF3D82;
}

.bg_6 {
  background: #FFF056;
}

.bg_7 {
  background: #558C89;
}

.bg_8 {
  background: #7D1935;
}

.bg_9 {
  background: #ffffff;
}


/*for hover change*/

.hov_1:hover {
  background: #4559EF;
}

.hov_2:hover {
  background: #EF2626;
}

.hov_3:hover {
  background: #14A91B;
}

.hov_4:hover {
  background: #835C3B;
}

.hov_5:hover {
  background: #DF3D82;
}

.hov_6:hover {
  background: #FFF056;
}

.hov_7:hover {
  background: #558C89;
}

.hov_8:hover {
  background: #7D1935;
}

.hov_9:hover {
  background: #ffffff;
}


/*for transition duration*/

.td-1 {
  transition: all .5s;
}

.td-2 {
  transition: all 1s;
}

.td-3 {
  transition: all 2s;
}

.td-4 {
  transition: all 3s;
}

.td-5 {
  transition: all 5s;
}

.td-6 {
  transition: all 8s;
}

.td-7 {
  transition: all 10s;
}

.td-8 {
  transition: all 20s;
}

.td-9 {
  transition: all 30s;
}

.td-10 {
  transition: all 60s;
}

.td-11 {
  transition: all 100s;
}

.td-1:hover {
  transition: all 0s;
}

.td-2:hover {
  transition: all 0s;
}

.td-3:hover {
  transition: all 0s;
}

.td-4:hover {
  transition: all 0s;
}

.td-5:hover {
  transition: all 0s;
}

.td-6:hover {
  transition: all 0s;
}

.td-7:hover {
  transition: all 0s;
}

.td-8:hover {
  transition: all 0s;
}

.td-9:hover {
  transition: all 0s;
}

.td-10:hover {
  transition: all 0s;
}

.td-11:hover {
  transition: all 0s;
}

.ef-1 {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.ef-2 {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.ef-3 {
  transform: rotateZ(180deg);
}

.ef-4 {
  transform: rotateX(540deg);
}

.ef-5 {
  transform: rotateY(540deg);
}

.ef-6 {
  transform: rotateZ(540deg);
}

.ef-7 {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(180deg) rotateX(180deg);
}

.ef-6 {
  transform: rotateZ(540deg) rotateY(540deg) rotateX(540deg);
}

.ef-8 {
  transform: rotateZ(3600deg) rotateY(3600deg) rotateX(3600deg);
}

.ef-1:hover {
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
}

.ef-2:hover {
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
}

.ef-3:hover {
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
}

.ef-4:hover {
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
}

.ef-5:hover {
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
}

.ef-6:hover {
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
}

.ef-7:hover {
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
}

.ef-6:hover {
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
}

.ef-8:hover {
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="bg_col_1"> Blue</button>
<button id="bg_col_2"> Red</button>
<button id="bg_col_3"> Green</button>
<button id="bg_col_4"> Brown</button>
<button id="bg_col_5"> Pink</button>
<button id="bg_col_6"> Yellow</button>
<button id="bg_col_7"> Ocean</button>
<button id="bg_col_8"> Magenta</button>
<button id="bg_col_9"> White</button>
<br>

<button id="hov_col_1"> Blue</button>
<button id="hov_col_2"> Red</button>
<button id="hov_col_3"> Green</button>
<button id="hov_col_4"> Brown</button>
<button id="hov_col_5"> Pink</button>
<button id="hov_col_6"> Yellow</button>
<button id="hov_col_7"> Ocean</button>
<button id="hov_col_8"> Magenta</button>
<button id="hov_col_9"> White</button>
<br>

<button id="t-1">.5s</button>
<button id="t-2">1s</button>
<button id="t-3">2s</button>
<button id="t-4">3s</button>
<button id="t-5">5s</button>
<button id="t-6">8s</button>
<button id="t-7">10s</button>
<button id="t-8">20s</button>
<button id="t-9">30s</button>
<button id="t-10">60s</button>
<button id="t-11">100s</button>
<br>

<button id="e-0">None</button>
<button id="e-1">Effect-1</button>
<button id="e-2">Effect-2</button>
<button id="e-3">Effect-3</button>
<button id="e-4">Effect-4</button>
<button id="e-5">Effect-5</button>
<button id="e-6">Effect-6</button>
<button id="e-7">Effect-7</button>
<button id="e-8">Effect-8</button>

<br>

<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
```

[code link](http://codepen.io/mayurbirle/pen/PpXpPE)

Any help is appriciated, Thanx

Comment: Not saying this is the culprit but you should cache your elements. Every time you do `$( '.def_anim' )` you're querying the DOM. Instead query once and re-use, `var $def_anim = $( '.def_anim' );` then you can do `$def_anim.toggleClass().removeClass()`. Also, everything seems to be working fine on my machine. Tested on Chrome, Firefox and IE11.

Comment: For me everything works fast. Might really be your machine.

Comment: it fast on snippet, may be because i deleted 1/2 tags, but slow again when  use aroung 1500 tags. any ways  i used var $def_anim = $( '.def_anim' );   seems litle faster and delete some tags for more speed. thnx for help  check it on http://codepen.io/mayurbirle/pen/PpXpPE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as the slowness issue goes, I would take this problem up with Codepen. I checked your code in the snippet you provided, and it works great. However, when I checked it on Codepen, it was super slow like you said. Thus, I think this is a processing problem on Codepen's end.

As far as the copy paste problem goes, you could try using Pug or something similar to rewrite your HTML. Here's what your long list of `p` tags would look like in Pug:

```
- for (var x = 0; x < 5; x++)
     p
```

This compiles to:

```
<!-- Five just like in the loop -->
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
```

Here's the link for Pug's docs: https://pugjs.org/language/code.html